# How to browse Windows XP from Mac Finder when name disappears from finder

Tags: windows, macos, file-sharing

Occasionally, like right at this moment, I cannot access my windows share from my mac.

Normally, it works, but every now and then, the computer name won't be displayed under SHARED in Finder.  Rebooting the windows computer usually fixes this, but it's inconvenient.  The Windows computer can see the Mac on the network.

Is there a method of asking finder to poll for windows shares again, or "forcing" finder to look for "desktop"?  I'm looking for the equivalent of \desktop in the address bar of a Windows computer.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Finder -> Go -> Connect to Server?

Comment: Does not appear to work, tried before asking question :)

Comment: `\\desktop` (Windows) and `smb://desktop` (Mac OS X) are equivalent. If this does not work, have you tried entering desktop's IP address? What's the error message?

Comment: I don't recall the specific error.  Perhaps something along the line of "could not find server xxx".

Comment: As @DanielBeck suggested, using the IP address instead of the host name to access the server might help. Of course it would be practical to have a fixed IP address for the host in that case.

Answer (score 0):

I encounter Windows machines which occasionally stop sharing their network drives and usually need to be rebooted to fix this. On the Windows machine, you can try the following commands which work for me once in a while:

```
net stop server
net start server
```

This will stop and restart the service that controls sharing network paths.

Comment: I'll give that a try next time it goes south.  I'm pretty sure winxx computers still have share access.